# Adding filter to ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm currently making a front-end with Angular.
I have a JSON file like following:

```
{
    "groups": [
           group1: {
                    "part":1
                   },
           group2: {
                    "part":2
                   }
              ]
}
```

And I have lists like following:

```
<li ng-class="{active: section >= {{group.number}}}" ng-bind="group.title" ng-repeat="group in groups" ></li>
```

Let's say there are 100 groups in my JSON file. If I want to only show groups with `"part":1`, how do I add this filter in ng-repeat?

Comment: The JSON is wrong groups is an array but have key-values in it.

Comment: Your JSON Array is wring, check this example http://plnkr.co/edit/8K0roOawfApaNq4yFjQh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an object to `filter` with the key/value you want to filter on:

```
ng-repeat="group in groups | filter:{part:1}"
```

Comment: if I want to make `1` value dynamic, how can I increase? do I make another div outside the list with ng-repeat? I want to increase from 1 to 10 eventually.

Comment: You would make the filter based on a model, as [shown in the docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter).

Comment: You can use scope variable for filter for achieving dynamic example: http://plnkr.co/edit/8K0roOawfApaNq4yFjQh

Comment: @BrettDeWoody, so I just call `filter:part` then?

Comment: As others haven't mentioned, you might need to cleanup the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
ng-repeat="group in groups | filter:{'part': 1}:true"
```

from official documentation

> In HTML Template Binding
>   {{ filter_expression | filter : expression :
>   comparator}}

for comparator value if its `true`

> true: A shorthand for function(actual, expected) { return
>   angular.equals(actual, expected)}. This is essentially strict
>   comparison of expected and actual.

this gives you the exact match

Answer (score 1):

Consider also passing a `function` rather than `Object` into [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) (which may work this time, but not all things are easily expressible in a readable fashion directly in the view):

```
ng-repeat="group in groups | filter:functionOnScope"
```

The `|` pipe operates on the thing to the left `groups`, so `filter` is a function whose first argument receives `groups` and whose subsequent arguments appear after the `:`.  You could visualize `a | b:c:d | e` as `e(b(a,c,d))` - once I realized that I used filters more for simple things.

So the second argument `filter` receives is a *predicate* (function that takes in something and returns `true` or `false` to operate on each element - like a SQL WHERE clause) inside `groups`.  Filters are super useful - if you have quick logic or transformations you want to do in the view (and you don't need to test it) then they can make your controllers and directives more succinct.  (So instead of `ng-if="collection[collection.length - 1].length > 0"` you could write `ng-if="collection | last | some"`, which is much more readable.)

If you have complicated logic, it may be better to put in a controller or directive instead of the view (this is also easier to unit test that way if you care about it) - if it's in the view you need something like PhantomJS at a minimum to emulate the DOM.  Assuming you bound some `dynamicallySelectedPart` on the `$scope` to `1`, `2`, etc. maybe as an `ng-model` on a `<select />` so the user can select it, then you can just write this to keep it dynamically up-to-date.

```
$scope.functionOnScope = function (elementInGroups) {
    // Maybe do a check like:
    // if ($scope.dynamicallySelectedPart === elementInGroups.part) {
    return true;
    // }

    // Some other logic...
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

- Your JSON looks malformed in that you have an array with key-value pairs.
- Below is some code that should work.  I am using the Controller ViewAs syntax.

HTML

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
<div ng-controller="MyController as me">
  {{me.greeting}}
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="group in me.groups | filter:{'part': 1}:true">
      {{group}}
    </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('MyApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyController', function() {
  this.greeting = 'Hola!';

  this.groups = [ {id: 'group1', "part":1 }, {id: 'group2',  "part":2 } ];
});
```

[Code Pen Here](http://codepen.io/thinkjones/pen/yOqwgN)